# Telerik RadComboBox selected value using jquery in external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, radcombobox

I have a Telerik RadComboBox and need to get the selected value (not text) from it.

My problem is I need to get it in an external javascript file so I cannot use the

```
var comboBox = $find("<%= RadComboBox1.ClientID %>"); 
var selectedValue = comboBox.get_value();
```

I can get the text from the external javascript file using jquery by doing

```
$('#RadComboBox1').val();
```

but I cannot get the value.

Comment: i don't think  u can get text of radcombobox1 in external js file

Comment: $('#RadComboBox1') this will never find RadComboBox1

Comment: $('#RadComboBox1').val(); that line right there gets me the text but I need the value not the text.